# Print price when item is in shoppingcar array

Tags: php

i already have the output of the items and the amount of the item but now i am trying to print out the price of the item but it is not working.

This is the page of the shoppingcar

```
<?php
//script opdracht1a.php
session_start();
// lees dit als: in de winkelwagen zitten 3 boeken en 1 pet
$_SESSION['winkelwagen'] = array( 'boek' => 3, 'pet' => 1 );

?>
```

And at this page i want to print out the products and amounts of `'winkelwagen'` but next to it i also need to print out the prices of the products of array `$aPrijzen`

Here is the second code of the other page

```
session_start();    
$aPrijzen = array ('boek' => 5, 'pet'=> 8 , 'jas' => 10, 'jurk' => 22); 
$winkelwagen = $_SESSION['winkelwagen'];

foreach($winkelwagen as $key => $value)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($aPrijzen); $i++)
    if($value == $aPrijzen)
    {
        echo $key.' '.$value.' '.$aPrijzen[i].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your arrays? (just enough to get the idea)

Comment: How can a value be equal to an array? ($value = $aPrijzen) ?

Comment: @kip accept the answer pls if it worked

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified to:

```
$aPrijzen = array ('boek' => 5, 'pet'=> 8 , 'jas' => 10, 'jurk' => 22);
foreach($_SESSION['winkelwagen'] as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset($aPrijzen[$key]))
    {
        echo $key.' '.$value.' '.$aPrijzen[$key].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: @KipVerslaafde no problem. Click the tick to accept the answer :)